# How to get ajax errors to be shown separately

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I'm using ajax to submit my laravel 5.2 form. The problem I'm having is that I'm struggling to get the errors to show separately. What happens is if I submit my form the errors show up twice

> The name field is required.,The surname field is required.
>
> The name field is required.,The surname field is required.

but what I would like is this, where in the source could it would show up like this

```
<li class="errors">The name field is required.</li>
<li class="errors">The surname field is required.</li>
```

This is my ajax code

```
$('.form').submit(function(event){ 
    event.preventDefault();          
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ceromony_post',
        type: "post",
        data: {'name':$('input[name=name]').val(), 
                'surname':$('input[name=surname]').val(), 
                'email':$('input[name=email]').val(), 
                'attendance':$('input[type=radio]:checked').val(), 
                'no_guest':$('input[name=no_guest]').val(), 
                'guests':$('textarea[name=guests]').val(), 
                '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()
            },
            success:function(data){
                $(".success_wrapper").append('<div class="success">'+data.message+'</div>');
                $(".form")[0].reset();
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                var errors = xhr.responseJSON;
                var error = [errors.name[0], errors.surname[0]];

                $.each(error, function(){
                    console.log(error);
                    $(".errors ul").append('<div class="errors">'+error+'</div>');
                });
            }
    });    
});
```

**UPDATE
This is what I have in my console

```
["The name field is required.", "The surname field is required."]
["The name field is required.", "The surname field is required."]
```

Comment: Maybe it's a typo, but you're appending `<div>` instead of `<li>`

Comment: oops. sorry I didn't change that, but even when I put the `<li>` I still get the same problem

Comment: In order to help you, maybe you should show us what's inside the `error` variable